# Error when authenticating user with Facebook API 4 with regular users

Tags: php, facebook, codeigniter, facebook-graph-api

I have a web app that posts content to users facebook's written in PHP with CodeIgniter using Facebook SDK v4.

The app works normally when the user logged in is the account where the APP is registered, but when trying to log in with a regular user I get the message:

```
Application not configured: This App developers didn't configured the app correctly to log in with Facebook
```

What am I missing? Why is it only working with the user who created the APP?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change settings on your Facebook App configuration and change the **Status & Review** as follow:

1. Open: https://developers.facebook.com/
2. Click on **Apps** on the top navigation, once dropdown is opened, click on your app, which you have created.
3. Once the corresponding App's page is opened, from the left side go to **Status & Review**
4. Set the answer **YES** to this question: Do you want to make this app and all its live features available to the general public?

And that's it.